# How can I add a Google Now card from corresponding search result card?

Tags: google-now

I am interested in exchange rates for some currency pairs. So I would like to see updates for them in my Google Now. Google search result for query `usd eur` gives nice card (as shown in the picture below). Is it possible to somehow "convert" it to Google Now card? And with updates?

[image: Google search card]

<sup>Click the image for larger variant</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do that, no. You can add each currency to your interested stocks by opening the Google Now menu > Customize > Stocks, but I don't know if that will do what you're looking for.

Comment: This is technically the correct answer, though based on my experience it only shown stocks, but not forex (although you can add it).